# How to change unity editor title format forever

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

current unity editor title format is like following:

```
Unity - Unity 2017.4.6f1 Personal (64bit) - TestMoveAndJump.unity - Ro.Unity - PC, Mac & Linux Standalone <OpenGL 4.5>
```

it's hard to recognize in app switcher and taskbar since "Unity - Unity 2017.4.6f1 Personal (64bit)" it's too long, I hope put unity project name to first, for ex:

```
Ro.Unity Unity - Unity 2017.4.6f1 Personal (64bit) - TestMoveAndJump.unity - Ro.Unity - PC, Mac & Linux Standalone <OpenGL 4.5>
```

how should i do, I can change unity window title in system c++ but I find unity editor title will be reset in many case, so I hope a way to set unity editor title in unity editor script

Comment: I was confused by the question title, but upon seeing what you mean.... *This is a good question,* I'd like to know too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you have tried and if this is what you mean by "system c++", but i've successfully changed the title using this. (You need to attach this to a GameObject)

Only works on Windows tho.. But i'll throw this in here anyway.

```
[ExecuteInEditMode]
public class TitleChanger : MonoBehaviour
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "SetWindowText")]
    public static extern bool SetWindowText(System.IntPtr hwnd, System.String lpString);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern System.IntPtr GetActiveWindow();

    void Start()
    {
        IntPtr windowPtr = GetActiveWindow();
        SetWindowText(windowPtr, Application.productName  + " [" + Application.unityVersion +"]");
    }

    void OnRenderObject()
    {
        IntPtr windowPtr = GetActiveWindow();
        SetWindowText(windowPtr, Application.productName + " [" + Application.unityVersion + "]");
    }
}
```

There are alot of methods in unity to get information to put in your title, `Application` has a few, if you want the current scene you could do `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().name` etc.

Edit:
I noticed the title would drop when saving my project, however after i added `OnRenderObject` to the code above, that is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

my current solution is check and change title in EditorApplication.update, I use linux xdotool to get and set title, I think windows and mac has similar soluiton, it will very slow if i open too many unity editor, I still wanna find a native way to get and set unity editor title

```
    [InitializeOnLoad]
    public class ChangeUnityEditorWindowTitle : MonoBehaviour
    {
        // unity editor will auto reset editor title in many cases
        static ChangeUnityEditorWindowTitle()
        {
            EditorApplication.update += ChangeTitleWhenSceneOnRuntime;
        }

        private static DateTime lastTime;

        private static void ChangeTitleWhenSceneOnRuntime()
        {
            if ((DateTime.Now - lastTime).TotalSeconds > 1)
            {
                lastTime = DateTime.Now;
                ChangeTitle();
            }
        }

        static string GetCurEditorTitle()
        {
            if (curWid != null)
            {
                return Shsu($"xdotool getwindowname {curWid}").Trim();
            }

            return null;
        }

        private static string _curWid;

        private static string curWid
        {
            get
            {
                if (_curWid == null)
                {
                    var cmd = $"xdotool search --onlyvisible --name \"Unity - Unity.*- {GetProjectName()} -\"";
//            var cmd = $"xdotool search --onlyvisible --pid {pid}";
                    _curWid = Shsu(cmd).Split("\n")[0].Trim();
                }

                return _curWid;
            }
        }

        private static string GetProjectName()
        {
            return RoFile.Basename(EditorUtil.GetProject());
        }

        private static string newTitle;

        [MenuItem("Ro/Change Unity Editor Window Title")]
        static void ChangeTitle()
        {
            var title = GetCurEditorTitle();
            var pjName = GetProjectName();
            if (title.IsMatch(@"Unity - Unity"))
            {
                if (!title.IsMatch($"^{pjName}"))
                {
                    if (newTitle == null)
                    {
                        newTitle = $"{pjName} - {title}";
                    }

                    Debug.Log($"Set unity editor title as \"{newTitle}\" ");
                    Shsu($"xdotool set_window --name \"{newTitle}\" {curWid}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```